# allocation failed for scaled bitmap - Xamarin Visual Studio

Tags: android, memory, xamarin, crash, xamarin.android

I have a home page which is rich with images(20KB to 300KB feeds fectched online). I have another page which displays contacts and their images(20KB to 300KB) in a refactored circle. On the contact page, it is a tab with 3 fragments. When i switch from fragement 1 to 2 to  3 and repeat vice versa, my app stops working and throw an error.

Also, when the app launches the home page and i scroll through the feeds, when i move to the next activity (contact page), it lags a bit before it gets to the contact page (after some seconds, it crashes). Looking into my log, this is what i see and i have been trying finding my way through.

In all my activities, i included `GC.Collect()` to get more spaces for other activities but still not working for me.

I have by the way increase the java heap size in my application to 1G. I have also handled bitmaps on my contact page.

Any idea of what is causing this issue?

**Exception**

```
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.Design[0x7cf85210] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI[0x7ce7c4a8]: 4
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method_a'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method_a'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method_a'.
[Adreno-EGL] <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
[Adreno-EGL] OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.07
[Adreno-EGL] Build Date: 01/22/14 Wed
[Adreno-EGL] Local Branch: base_au149_adreno_au169_patches
[Adreno-EGL] Remote Branch: 
[Adreno-EGL] Local Patches: 
[Adreno-EGL] Reconstruct Branch: 
[OpenGLRenderer] Enabling debug mode 0
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_int_method'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_int_method'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_int_method'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat[0x7d0e4ac0] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat[0x7bbff618]: 4
[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 43.690MB for 14449048-byte allocation
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[Mono] GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 24 objects 34 opaque 8 colors 24 colors-bridged 24 colors-visible 24 xref 6 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.05ms tarjan 0.10ms scc-setup 0.05ms gather-xref 0.00ms xref-setup 0.00ms cleanup 0.04ms
[Mono] GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 25.34ms
[Mono] GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 784K in use: 199K
[Mono] GC_MAJOR: (user request) time 3.53ms, stw 3.72ms los size: 1024K in use: 8K
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment[0x7cfeb058] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI[0x7ce7c4a8]: 5
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_get_field_id'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_field_id'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_get_field_id'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_get_int_field'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_int_field'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_get_int_field'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView[0x7d4d3508] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI[0x7ce7c4a8]: 6
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_get_object_array_element'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_object_array_element'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_get_object_array_element'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_set_boolean_field'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_set_boolean_field'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_set_boolean_field'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_set_int_field'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_set_int_field'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_set_int_field'.
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #2
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #3
[Mono] [0x853813e8] worker starting
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
[Mono] [0x85e6fb88] worker starting
[Mono] [0x85e6ffd8] worker starting
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
[Mono] [0x85e7bcf8] worker starting
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_field_id'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_field_id'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_field_id'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_object_field'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_object_field'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_object_field'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_boolean_method_a'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_boolean_method_a'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_boolean_method_a'.
[Mono] [0x85e6ffd8] hill climbing, change max number of threads 4
[Choreographer] Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[Mono] [0x85e6ffd8] hill climbing, change max number of threads 5
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #7
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #8
[Mono] [0x85de0cb8] worker starting
[Mono] [0x85e19438] worker starting
[dalvikvm-heap] Clamp target GC heap from 134.009MB to 128.000MB
[dalvikvm-heap] Clamp target GC heap from 138.888MB to 128.000MB
[dalvikvm-heap] Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1575952-byte allocation
[dalvikvm-heap] Clamp target GC heap from 142.888MB to 128.000MB
[dalvikvm-heap] Out of memory on a 1575952-byte allocation.
[skia] --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
[dalvikvm-heap] Clamp target GC heap from 142.888MB to 128.000MB
[dalvikvm-heap] Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 921616-byte allocation
[dalvikvm-heap] Clamp target GC heap from 142.888MB to 128.000MB
[dalvikvm-heap] Out of memory on a 921616-byte allocation.
[skia] --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
[Mono] Image addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0x82d6fad0] -> System.Runtime.Serialization.dll[0x82d6ece8]: 2
[Mono] Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization' (System.Runtime.Serialization.dll)
[Mono] Assembly System.Runtime.Serialization[0x82d6fad0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT: image 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-115/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-115/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization.config'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0x7d63cb60] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0x82d6fad0]: 2
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0x82d6fad0] -> mscorlib[0x72798a08]: 31
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #5
[Mono] [0x85e6ffd8] worker finishing
```

Comment: `java heap size in my application to 1G` ? There is no such heap size setting...

Comment: @SushiHangover, There is . In my Visual Studio project solution. I was following other related issues and i found that.

Comment: You must be setting the heap size of the Java partition of the Xamarin **build** process....

Comment: @SushiHangover, exactly. Sorry about not making that clearer. By the way, do you have any idea to my issue please. Been at this for days

Answer (score 0):

You can request `LargeHeap` within your manifest or via an attribute on your `Application` subclass

#### Manifest (Application Section)

```
android:largeHeap
```

#### Application subclass attribute:

```
[Application(LargeHeap = true)]
public class XamarinAndroidApp : Application
{
   ~~~~
}
```

This is **just a request** and depending upon the device you may or may not get an increased Java/Dalvik heap and your app should *not* rely on getting the increased heap size.

> Most apps should not need this and should instead focus on reducing their overall memory usage for improved performance. Enabling this also does not guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because some devices are constrained by their total available memory.

As your error shows, your Java heap is constrained to `128MB` on that device and that is moderate heap size as they can range as low as 16MB on older low-end devices and on newer high-end devices this can go up to 512MB (and more on certain devices). But note, the heap size is *not* variable per device and is hardwired (`/system/build.prop`) and you can not control it other then having your app request a `LargeHeap`.

#### The real solution involves:

- Ensuring that you have profiled your app's allocations and are not leaking memory
- You are not holding references to Bitmaps via a hidden or non-displayed `Fragment`, `View`, etc.. in such a way that they can not be collected and released
- You are using a Bitmap cache (i.e. `LruCache`) to manage how many `Bitmap`s are been held in memory at any give time
- That the Bitmaps that are actually being held in memory are sized appropriately for the device's resolution, i.e.:

  - Resizing content on the device on the fly and file caching the results
  - Dynamically via the web service that you are requesting them from